# Solution , Solubility and Colligative Property?

Tags: solutions, solubility

Which of the following  0.1 M aqueous solution will have the lowest freezing point ?

1) Glucose 
2) Urea 
3) NaCl 
4) K2SO4

How to relate Molarity with freezing point ?
Should I use the relation 
Kf = MR(Tf)2/1000Hv

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have some ice.

[image]

Beautiful structure. Ice stays solid at some temperatures because of its neat, tight lattice. Ice stacks this over and over until there's no more ice left to stack.

If I were to put a lot of ions between this stack, the stack might bend or even break; it isn't as reinforcing as it once was. The stack isn't as durable anymore, so we would expect it to melt a lot easier - there's too much structural stress for it to be a solid.

The freezing point of solutions depends, at least in this case, on how much dissociation occurs. If we can push more ions into solution, it's going to have a harder time making a sturdy lattice - a harder time freezing.

$\ce{C6H6O6 -> C6H6O6}$ It doesn't dissociate at all.

I'm not sure how much urea dissociates, but I assume it would be like glucose.

$\ce{NaCl -> Na+ + Cl-}$ It dissociates into 2 ions.

$\ce{K2SO4 -> K+ + K+ + SO4^{2-}}$ It dissociates into 3 ions.

$\ce{K2SO4}$ dissociates the most, so it's freezing point is lowest. Hope this helps!